# Is it possible to catch page change event using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

is there any way for jQuery to catch page change event ?

for example I have few `<a>` tags which will route to another page,

```
<a href="http://127.0.0.1/page1.html">page1</a>
<a href="http://127.0.0.1/page2.html">page2</a>
<a href="#local">local</a>
<a href="http://127.0.0.1/page4.html">page4</a>
```

What I wanted to achieve is, when the user click on any link that will navigate to other page, the loading bar will show up

instead of add 'onclick' for each of the link,

```
<a href="http://127.0.0.1/page1.html" onclick="openLoader()">page1</a>
function openLoader(){ $('#loading').show();}
```

Comment: I suspect there is any, as hyperlink will refresh the page, the only way you can do is to load the progress bar function in ever page load

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WindowEventHandlers.onhashchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange)

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function(e){
 // Your Code goes here
});
```

Comment: sorry still cant